# Export SharePoint 2010 SP2 site to SP1 SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, content-database

After patching our Test environment of SharePoint 2010 to Service Pack 2, Our project leader told me there is a website that need to go to production. Production is still in SP1. He planned with me to give the patching priority and told nothing about the sites.

The sites have their own content databases. The problem is that i'm not sure now if it is possible to move the sites to production. I hope you can give me some insight in this. Normally we do backup -> Restore -> attach.

Comment: You can't restore anything that have a different patch level. So you're only option is to patch Production to SP2.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I guess when you export as template with content, you hit the same problem?

Comment: Yes, when you update SharePoint, the databases get updated to. So sadly there is no way to do it. If you don't have an additional environment/single server with the same patch level as your production where you can recreate this site and export it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will discuss the problem with him and look on how to replan it. Production need to be patched, Development and test are already patched. I feared it won't be possible, but now i'm sure.

Comment: You're assumptions were right. But i think it would be god to evaluate the patched test environment and then patch production before moving anything. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can go from Higher Patch / build level to Lower( in your case from SP2 to SP1). But i am thinking about couple of possible workaround.

- if you have frequent backup of your Test farm databases then restore the database from backup and then from Production Central admin take the backup of site collection using the [Recover content from an unattached content database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269601(v=office.14).aspx) . But again this is totally depend upon on the backup availability.
- Another option is use the 3rd party tool i.e ShareGate( they have 15 days trial). With the help of tool you can move the sites irrespective of version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. ShareGate is an option to test out when the sites need to be moved before test is validated and production patched.